# How to send parametes to cloud with parse.cloud.run

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to send some data from textbox and with click to cloud to do a function. I know that Parse.Cloud.run(name, data, options) but so far i have tried to do it like this. I'm new in coding so i don't know if it is possible the way i'm trying to do it.
my code that is included in html:

```
function calculate(){
            var inches=parseFloat(document.getElementById("textbox1").value);
            Parse.initialize("APP_ID", "App_key");
            Parse.Cloud.run('calc', {inches}, {
            success: function(result) {
alert(result);
$(".success").show();
},
error: function(error) {
   $(".error").show();
  }
  });
}
```

In js file in cloud I have:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("calc", function(request, response){
  var answer
  request.params(inches);
  answer= inches*2.54;
  response.success(answer);
});
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

The payload you are sending should be formatted as JSON.

```
...
Parse.Cloud.run('calc', { inches: inches }, {
...
```

Then received as follows:

```
...
var answer = request.params.inches * 2.54;
...
```

Take a look at the documentation for running cloud code functions from JavaScript to see more examples: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=JavaScript#functions-calling